# TypeScript AngularJS local storage service to access IndexedDB, database instance is undefined?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, indexeddb

I am writing in TypeScript AngularJS local storage service to access IndexedDB.
Implemented open() function to open a connection to IndexedDB and assigned database instance to a variable **database** of type IDBDatabase (this.database)

When I assign:

> this.database = (event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result

I confirmed that **this.database** holds the instance of the database.
However, the problem is - when I call getForms() from my controller, **this.database** is undefined :(

Please advice why this is happening and how to solve this problem. Thank you.

**Here is the code for my service:**

```
namespace App {
    "use strict";

    export class LocalStorage {
        indexedDB: IDBFactory;
        dbName: string;
        tableName: string;
        lastIndex: number;
        database: IDBDatabase;

        static $inject: string[] = ["$window", "$q"];

        constructor(private $window: ng.IWindowService, private $q: ng.IQService) {
            this.indexedDB = $window.indexedDB;
            this.lastIndex = 0;
            this.dbName = "entities";
            this.tableName = "keyvaluepairs";
        }

        open() {
            var deferred = this.$q.defer();
            var request = this.indexedDB.open(this.dbName);
            request.onsuccess = function (event: Event) {
                this.database = (event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result;
                deferred.resolve();
            };

            request.onerror = function (event: Event) {
                deferred.reject();
            };

            return deferred.promise;
        };


        getForms() {
            var deferred = this.$q.defer();

            // Problem here: this.database for some reason is undefined,
            // although I have instantiated it in the open() function

            if (this.database) { 

                // my code comes here...
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        };

    }

    app.service("LocalStorage", LocalStorage);

}
```

**Below is the code for my controller:**

```
namespace App {
    "use strict";

    /**
     * DetailController
     */
    class DetailController {
        id: number = 15424420;
        form: any;
        message: string;

        static $inject: string[] = ["LocalStorage", "$filter"];

        constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorage, private $filter: ng.IFilterService) {
            this.localStorage.open().then(
                response => this.getForms(), 
                response => this.error(response));
        }

        getForms() {
            this.localStorage.getForms().then(
                response => this.success(response),
                response => this.error(response));
        }

        // Apply filter to find the form we need by ID
        success(data) {
            this.form = this.$filter("filter")(data, { Id: this.id })[0];
            this.message = this.form.Name;

        }

        error(response) {
            this.form = null;
            this.message = response.error.statusText;
        }
    }

    app.controller("DetailController", DetailController);
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are resolving this.database asynchronously are you sure the onSuccess call is executed before you call getForms?

Comment: I just noticed you call get forms when that promise resolves so.. yes..